# Total order on constructive real numbers

Tags: real-numbers, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

Is there a definition of the real numbers in constructive or intuitionistic logic such as the order is total, ie
$$ \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R},\; x \leq y \lor y \leq x $$
The classical proof of this totality usually starts with an excluded middle, asserting that either $x\leq y$ or not. The negative case leads to $y\leq x$. But in constructive logic we cannot use this excluded middle.

According to this [page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/real+number), the definitions of the real numbers by Cauchy sequences or Dedekind cuts are not equivalent. Maybe one has the total order and not the other.

Without a total order I don't think we can say much about real numbers. For example, would a $x\in\mathbb{R}$ even have decimal expansion or integer part ? Usually those involve finding the smallest integer greater than $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In intuitionistic mathematics, what we have is $$\forall x,y\quad x\#{}y\to x<y \lor y<x$$
where $\#$ is the intuitionistic notion of [apartness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apartness_relation).  Now, if we define equality in terms of apartness and negation $$x=y\equiv{\lnot{x\# y}}$$ we have
$$\forall{x,y}\quad \lnot (\lnot (x\leq y) \land \lnot (y\leq x))$$
which is classically, **but not intuitionistically**, equivalent to
$$\forall x,y\quad x\leq y \lor y\leq x$$

Naturally, intuitionistic real numbers, which are defined by computable Cauchy sequences, can still have decimal expansions and integer parts.